# How to update Table view ? I am adding views to table view on runtime

Tags: android, android-layout

Can i update table view at runtime ? I am adding views to table view at runtime and i wants to update as n when i am adding views to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use TableRow row=new TableRow(this);
row.addView(view);
tblView.addView(row);

Comment: This will add views to tableview but i won't get updated until n unless i will touch the screen.  I want to update my activity when my view is added to tableView.

Comment: invoke invalidate on tblView, your entire tblView would be refreshed.